# Property shown as Object when a type is specified

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, compilation

Ok. I'm programing since 15 years now, and I have a really-REALLY weird behavior here where I have a pretty simple class, which expose a property that have a number of results from a private list of my class;

```
Public ReadOnly Property NumberOfResult() String Integer
  Get
    Return Me.mList.Count()
  End Get
End Property
```

For an unknown reason, the compiler tells me my property has a return type of `Object`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the return type.  It should be `As Integer` instead of `String Integer`.

Comment: Oh, you right ... but how the hell it does successfully compiles?!

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine...

Comment: Ah, the *magic* of `Option Strict Off`! Set it `On`.

Comment: It turns out that you can write as many keywords you want or even something that doesn't even exist; if you forget to type "as" keyword, it compiles ANYWAY! Wow... that's kind of weird! For sure, as @Jimi said, in case options strict isn't activated

Comment: Congratulations, you found a bug in the Roslyn VB compiler. The pre-Roslyn vb compilers will flag that with an "end of statement expected" error. Please consider reporting it:  Help Menu->Feedback->Report a Problem.

Comment: Well, I reported it.